# TinyTds::Error: Unable to open socket

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sockets, sql-server-2000, tiny-tds

I've researched this for a few hours now and I can't seem to find a solution.

I have a Rails 2 app that uses the TinyTds gem ( tiny_tds ) to connect to an SQL 2000 server hosted locally in our company.

The app has been connecting to SQL Server almost every day for the past 6 months with no problem.

Suddenly, when trying to connect yesterday, I started getting an error:

```
TinyTds::Error: Unable to open socket
from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/tiny_tds-0.4.5/lib/tiny_tds/client.rb:60:in `connect'
from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/tiny_tds-0.4.5/lib/tiny_tds/client.rb:60:in `initialize'
```

From my research, I've seen some people suggesting that I use 
SO_REUSEADDR  to allow it to connect and ignore timeout or "usage" restrictions, like this:
setsockopt(sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR)
but I cannot figure out how to use that command within the current context. 
I tried calling it in commmandline on the server and it won't work, but then again, I'm not sure what it does or if I can even call that from commandline.

I've tried calling
netstat -a 
which shows current sockets, but I'm not sure what to do with that information.

I've also seen that
service  restart
can restart a socket, but I'm not sure which socket to restart.

Lastly, in my freetds.conf configuration file, I have these settings:

```
host = 192.168.0.220 
port = 1433
tds version = 8.0
```

I'm not really sure which road to take.  I'm comfortable with Rails but this socket stuff is way outside my current understanding. This is also a Rails 2 app ( legacy ) which is key to some core processes our business uses. We can't upgrade to Rails 3 due to SQL server adapter gem for SQL 2000 Server won't work with Rails 3.

Can anyone help ?